# Is stream-format in h264 related to camera provided stream or is it more like transport thing?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, directshow

I've got camera that produces video stream in different formats. One of them is h264 encoded stream. I use dshow along with gstreamer to acquire this stream and process it with c++ and send it also via shared memory. My question is related specifically to field stream-format in gst caps. How do I know whether it is byte-stream or avc? Is it tightly coupled to stream produced by camera or is it like transport thing that I set with gstreamer by my own? I work with rather complicated commercial specific pipelines that I cannot share full here. When I set in my code `gst_caps_set_simple (gstCaps, "stream-format", G_TYPE_STRING, "byte-stream", nullptr);` it works but I am not 100% why so I want to clarify that.

I've tried checking information about this specific camera with ffmpeg but I cannot get info about stream-format. Best I got is:
`ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="nameOfCamera"`

```
(...)
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x480 fps=29.97
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x576 fps=25
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x480 fps=29.97
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x576 fps=25
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x480 fps=29.97
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x576 fps=25
vcodec=h264  min s=128x96 fps=0.015625 max s=768x576 fps=25
(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think the interface from how you get the data from should specify the data format.

`byte-stream` in GStreamer terms is the regular H.264 byte-stream as per H.264 specification with start codes, start code emulation bytes etc.

Alternatively `avc` samples can be an alternative format (MP4 files store H.264 data as AVC samples, and not byte-stream). AVC samples are basically `[nal length][nal data of length size]`... chunks (no start codes or start code emulation bytes).

AVC samples give you quick NAL chunk access, for the regular byte-stream would have to do a bit more parsing.

So you will have to set the type whatever you get into GStreamer so the downstream element knows what type of data to expect.